# Woocommerce: Replace products Add to cart element <a> with <button>

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

on main page I have products grid and I have add to cart button with such code

```
<a href="/?add-to-cart=2609" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="2609" ...
```

I want to replace it with button

```
<button data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="2609" ...
```

How could I?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to add the "woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link" filter inside functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'loop_add_to_cart_link_change_tag', 10, 3 );
function loop_add_to_cart_link_change_tag( $link_code, $product, $args ) {
    $r = array(
        '<a '  => '<button ',
        '</a>' => '</button>'
    );
    return strtr($link_code, $r);
}
```

Comment: thanks! that's it, but also I changed it a bit to consider cloth items with 'Select Option' text: ```if(strpos($link_code, 'options') === false) {
        return strtr($link_code, $r);
    } else {
        return $link_code;
    }```